# Tabletop Simulator - Textbox - Auto Re-Size Text?

Tags: lua, textbox, tabletop-simulator

I'm making a somewhat obscure and out-of-print game, Creatures & Cultists, available on Tabletop Simulator.  The player board has various text-boxes.  For two of those text-boxes, I need the text to reduce in size, when there's not enough room to display what the player types in.

I've made programs in C# and there's a built-in auto-resize feature that can be toggled on for fields like text-boxes.  Does the Tabletop Simulator LUA & API allow for such a feature?

I'm using the text-box template from Mr. Stump.

Parameters for one of the text-boxes:

```
--name Credo
        {
            pos       = {0.35,0.12,0.93},
            rows      = 1,
            width     = 6000,
            font_size = 450,
            label     = "",
            value     = "Enter in Cult Credo Here",
            alignment = 2,
            rotation  = {0,0,0},
            height    = 500,
            scale     = {0.1,0.0075,0.1},
        },
```

Those parameters are passed to the create_text-box function from Mr. Stump:

```
function create_textboxes()
for i, data in ipairs(ref_buttonData.house_inputs) do
    --Sets up reference function
    local funcName = "textboxes"..i
    local func = function(_,_,val,sel) click_textboxes(i,val,sel) end
    self.setVar(funcName, func)

    self.createInput({
        input_function = funcName,
        function_owner = self,
        label          = data.label,
        alignment      = data.alignment,
        position       = data.pos,
        scale          = buttonScale,
        width          = data.width,
        height         = (data.font_size*data.rows)+24,
        font_size      = data.font_size,
        color          = buttonColor,
        font_color     = buttonFontColor,
        value          = data.value,
        rotation       = data.rotation,
        height         = data.height,
        scale          = data.scale,
    })
end
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have found, this cannot be done using the inputs created in Lua. However, this effect can be accomplished by utilizing the [UI API](https://api.tabletopsimulator.com/ui/introUI/) which allows you to create elements using XML. You'll want to create something like the following:

```
<InputField resizeTextForBestFit="true"/>
```

The resizeTextForBestFit attribute can be found in the [Attributes Section](https://api.tabletopsimulator.com/ui/attributes/) of the UI API.

It takes a lot of code to get things running in Tabletop Simulator so for an in depth example of this code in action, you can reference this [character sheet](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2591338068&searchtext=dnd%20character%20sheet%205e) I made using the XML solution above.